# How do I run GUI applications as root by using pkexec?

Tags: gnome, environment-variables, pkexec

I am using [Trisquel](https://trisquel.info) GNU/Linux-Libre which comes with [Gnome3 Flashback](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback) Desktop Environment.

I know that I can run GUI application as root by `sudo` & `gksudo` but I want to know that How do I run GUI applications as root with the help of **`pkexec`**?

When I tries to run `gedit` (or any other application like:`nautilus`) by `pkexec gedit` then It prompts for password for authentication:-

[image: screenshot]

After entering password it exit with error:-

```
$ pkexec gedit
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(gedit:6135): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

---

So, It seems something is going wrong with display environment.

I've also tried with `DISPLAY=:0 pkexec gedit` but doesn't work.

---

Following information is available from `man pkexec`:-

> The environment that PROGRAM will run it, will be set to a minimal
>   known and safe environment in order to
>          avoid injecting code through LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar mechanisms. In addition the PKEXEC_UID environment
>          variable is set to the user id of the process invoking pkexec. As a result, pkexec will not allow you to run
>          X11 applications as another user since the $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY environment variables are not set. These
>          two variables will be retained if the org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui annotation on an action is
>   set
>          to a nonempty value; this is discouraged, though, and should only be used for legacy programs.

Now I don't know What to do in order to accomplish this.

Thus, Help me to find out How to run GUI applications as root by means of `pkexec`. Or **Is this possible or not?**

---

BTW, Inspired by `gparted-pkexec`command which works fine. How `gparted` use `pkexec`?

Comment: (Later on found) Related : [How to configure pkexec?](http://askubuntu.com/q/287845/256099)

Comment: Check out this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433209/282415) it worked for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It can be done by adding custom actions to policykit. If you want to run gedit as root with `pkexec` you have to create new file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.gedit.policy` for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
    <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.gedit">
    <description>Run gedit program</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run the gedit</message>
    <icon_name>accessories-text-editor</icon_name>
    <defaults>
        <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
        <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
        <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/gedit</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
    </action>
</policyconfig>
```

Finally `pkexec gedit` should work as expected.

---

Visit manpage or [Reference Manual](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html) which explains it with EXAMPLE like:-

```
$ man pkexec | grep -i ^Example -A 60
EXAMPLE
       To specify what kind of authorization is needed to execute the program /usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate as
       another user, simply write an action definition file like this

           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
            "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
            "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
           <policyconfig>

             <vendor>Examples for the PolicyKit Project</vendor>
             <vendor_url>http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/PolicyKit/</vendor_url>

             <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.example.pkexec.run-frobnicate">
               <description>Run the PolicyKit example program Frobnicate</description>
               <description xml:lang="da">Kør PolicyKit eksemplet Frobnicate</description>
               <message>Authentication is required to run the PolicyKit example program Frobnicate (user=$(user), program=$(program), command_line=$(command_line))</message>
               <message xml:lang="da">Autorisering er påkrævet for at afvikle PolicyKit eksemplet Frobnicate (user=$(user), program=$(program), command_line=$(command_line))</message>
               <icon_name>audio-x-generic</icon_name>
               <defaults>
                 <allow_any>no</allow_any>
                 <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
                 <allow_active>auth_self_keep</allow_active>
               </defaults>
               <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate</annotate>
             </action>

           </policyconfig>

       and drop it in the /usr/share/polkit-1/actions directory under a suitable name (e.g. matching the namespace of
       the action). Note that in addition to specifying the program, the authentication message, description, icon
       and defaults can be specified. Note that occurences of the strings $(user), $(program) and $(command_line) in
       the message will be replaced with respectively the user (of the form "Real Name (username)" or just "username"
       if there is no real name for the username), the binary to execute (a fully-qualified path, e.g.
       "/usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate") and the command-line, e.g. "pk-example-frobnicate foo bar". For example, for
       the action defined above, the following authentication dialog will be shown:

           [IMAGE][2]

               +----------------------------------------------------------+
               |                     Authenticate                     [X] |
               +----------------------------------------------------------+
               |                                                          |
               |  [Icon]  Authentication is required to run the PolicyKit |
               |          example program Frobnicate                      |
               |                                                          |
               |          An application is attempting to perform an      |
               |          action that requires privileges. Authentication |
               |          is required to perform this action.             |
               |                                                          |
               |          Password: [__________________________________]  |
               |                                                          |
               | [V] Details:                                             |
               |  Command: /usr/bin/pk-example-frobnicate                 |
               |  Run As:  Super User (root)                              |
               |  Action:  org.fd.pk.example.pkexec.run-frobnicate        |
               |  Vendor:  Examples for the PolicyKit Project             |
               |                                                          |
               |                                  [Cancel] [Authenticate] |
               +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @Pandya, the real error is "Refusing to render service to dead parents", there are some bug reports when i googled for it. For workaround you can create executable file in /usr/local/bin which contains something like: #! /bin/sh  "pkexec" "nautilus" and run it with F7. I think it should work.

Comment: OK. I've tried by making executable which is working fine with F7.

Comment: I'm really disappointed that such a tool forced me to configure something outside /etc and more worst under /usr/share instead of /usr/local/share.

Answer (score 13):

For me, with Ubuntu, to run **hardinfo** as *root*,

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY hardinfo
```

works well.
This tips is from [nany](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/profile.php?id=167020) ([french Ubuntu forum](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22395969#p22395969)).

Comment: Note that this only works on a system which sets `$XAUTHORITY` for the current user. If `$XAUTHORITY` is not set (e.g. on Debian), you will set it to an empty value for `hardinfo`, causing it to fail to access the display.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this for one user, then you can share the cookie for your current `$DISPLAY` with a given user, e.g. `root`, without using `pam_xauth`:

```
sudo xauth -f /root/.Xauthority add $(xauth list $DISPLAY)
```

Once you run this command (you should do it only once per session), you can run GUI programs with `pkexec` by simply sharing your `$DISPLAY`:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY gparted
```

Also note that you very rarely need to run an editor as `root`. If you need to change a file owned by a different user, you can do it on any reasonably modern system using GVfs:

```
gedit admin:///etc/fstab
```

This runs the polkit authentication agent (asking for a password) just like `pkexec` does, but instead of running the editor as root, it gives it unrestricted access to a single file.