# How can I send a notification with polkit 0.106?

Tags: linux, shutdown, polkit, notify-send

I am developing a application to don't forget the pendrive.

This app must lock the shutdown if a pendrive is connected to the machine. As this form, if the user wants to shutdown the system while a pendrive is connected, the system shows a notification to alert about it must disconnect the pendrive to unlock shutdown.

To detect the shutdown event, I set a polkit rule what call a script to check if any pendrive are connected to the system.

If there are any pendrive connected, the polkit rule calls to notify-send through the script `send_notify.sh`, which execute this command:

`notify-send "Pendrive-Reminder" "Extract Pendrive to enable shutdown" -t 5000`

The polkit rule is this:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions" || 
        action.id == "org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper")  
    {

        try{    
            polkit.spawn(["/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/check_pendrive.sh", subject.user]);        
            return polkit.Result.YES;

        }catch(error){
            polkit.spawn(["/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/send_notify.sh", subject.user]);
        return polkit.Result.NO;
     }
   }
  }
```

But. after put this polkit rule and press shutdown button, my user don't receive any notification.

I debug the rule and I checked that second script It's executed, but the `notify-send` don't shows the notification to my user.

How can I solve this?

UPDATE:

I tried to modify the script as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=$1

XAUTHORITY="/home/$user/.Xauthority"
DISPLAY=$( who | grep -m1 $user.*\( | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[(|)]//g')

notify-send "Extract Pendrive to enable shutdown" -t 5000

exit 0
```

The user is passed as parameter by pòlkit

But the problem continues

UPDATE: I've just seen this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/+bug/160598 that don't allows to send notifications as root.

Later I'll test to modify workaround changing user

UPDATE2: After change code to this. the problem continues:

```
#!/bin/bash

export XAUTHORITY="/home/$user/.Xauthority"
export DISPLAY=$(cat "/tmp/display.$user")

user=$1
su $user -c 'notify-send "Pendrive Reminder" "Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown" -u critical'
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this to be sure the pendrive is properly unmounted? Or are you trying to achieve something else? Because even if the pendrive is mounted, the shutdown sequence should ensure that it's properly unmounted

Comment: I added a line in script that write a file during the pendrive disconnection and, after disconnect the pendrive, the file has been created and writed correctly.

So, the second script is called correctly

Comment: Add `export DISPLAY XAUTHORITY` before notify-send.

Comment: ok, I'll try it

Comment: Added. Unsucessfull yet

Comment: Try `echo $DISPLAY $XAUTHORITY > /home/$user/x.txt` and check the content of `x.txt`. Also: Does the script run as user `$user`? There may be access restrictions to `.Xauthority` forbidding access for other users than `$user`.

Comment: You can also try `xmessage "yourtext"` to make sure its not a problem with notify-send itself.

Comment: ok, I'll try both

Comment: After try `echo $DISPLAY $XAUTHORITY > /home/$user/x.txt` from my script, I check that x.txt file don't exists after press shutdown button.

Comment: Either the script is not executed, or it cannot write to `/home/$user`. Try `echo $DISPLAY $XAUTHORITY $user > /tmp/x.txt`

Comment: I did a `echo $user > /tmp/user` and this file was created correcly with the username in it.

So feels the second problem

Comment: This only works with a X session (and not wayland one) and might break if several users are connected to the machine.

Comment: @Bigon what is your proposal to solve it?

Comment: What gives `echo $DISPLAY $XAUTHORITY $(id) > /tmp/x.txt`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I would create a daemon that listen to udev events and that set systemd inhibitor to prevent the reboot/shutdown. But that doesn't solve the problem of the notification (maybe some desktop environment would display something). Note that there are discussion in polkit mailing lists to remove the javascript support for the rules in the future and also note that polkit in debian has an old version that doesn't support that either. I'm still wondering WHY you want to do that.

Comment: @mviereck `15:30 /home/almu/.Xauthority uid=102(polkitd) gid=105(polkitd) groups=105(polkitd)`

Comment: @Bigon I have other version of same application that, instead use polkit javascript rules, use old polkit authoritization files (.pkga)

In this version, I have two scripts linked to 2 udev events. The first script, furthermore creates the usb file, add the pkla polkit file; and the second, after remove id from file, if file is empty, also remove pkla polkit file.

But this version don't allow show notifications

Comment: Full code here: https://github.com/AlmuHS/Pendrive_Reminder

Comment: One issue: `15:30` is not a valid value for `DISPLAY`. Most times it is `:0` or `:1`.  Another issue: most probably `polkitd` is not allowed to read `.Xauthority`.  I'll add a workaround to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I think is a permissions problem

Comment: Your rule file is very strange. I think only one catch the shutdown. First at all, you must find the responsible program consolekit, login1 or xfce. Perhaps it's another one ? When I try for your previous ask, the shutdown button was disabled when the pendrive file exist. No need of notification because I can't shutdown.

Comment: @ctac_
This rule is part of a program, which will be distributed and used by users with differents desktop environments and distributions. 

By this reason, my rule file capture all possible shutdown events of each desktop environment and system.

The program try to be a reminder, with objective that the user don't forget its pendrive. By this reason, furthermore to lock shutdown when user connect pendrive, is needed a notify when the user try to shutdown

Comment: Your script in UPDATE 2 can only work if `/tmp/display.$user` exists. Therefore you need the autostart script provided in my answer. Instead of `XAUTHORITY` it works with `xhost`.  You need to read and understand the script snippets to use them.

Comment: @mviereck
Well, It's a update based in your workaround. Previously, I put your script in my autostart, and execute it manually to be sure

Comment: This may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429162/185747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created a dbus client, launched as user, which receives signal from systembus and shows notification to user.

The dbus client code is in https://github.com/AlmuHS/Pendrive_Reminder/blob/work-in-progress/dbus-client/client.py

In the `send-notify.sh` script, I only added

```
 dbus-send --system /org/preminder/mensaje org.preminder.App
```

Executing the dbus client as user, the notification is showed correctly

Now I'm try that the client can be launched automatically when user connect pendrive

Continue in [How to launch a dbus client from a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433175/how-to-launch-a-dbus-client-from-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

polkit (and `pkexec`) delete environment variables `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` that are needed for X access. `notify-send` fails because it cannot access the display.

From the [pkexec manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/policykit-1/pkexec.1.en.html#SECURITY_NOTES):

> As a result, pkexec will not allow you to run X11 applications as another user since the $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY environment variables are not set. These two variables will be retained if the org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui annotation on an action is set to a nonempty value

I am not familar with polkit; maybe you can set `org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui` just for this rule, or there are other possibilities. Sorry that I can't provide a ready solution.

However, the core point is to provide `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` for `notify-send`.

(Don't hit me: a dirty solution would be hardcoding `DISPLAY=:0` and `XAUTHORITY=...` in your notify script. Be aware that this can fail if something changes).

---

Edit: Based on above discussion a workaround that should work with multiple users and without `XAUTHORITY`:

On X login, a script should be automatically executed (maybe some `.desktop` setup in `~/.config/autostart`):

```
#! /bin/bash
# allow polkitd access to X. 
# xhost is an alternative to XAUTHORITY authentication
xhost +SI:localuser:polkitd
# store DISPLAY for each user
echo $DISPLAY > /tmp/display.$USER
```

In your polkit script include

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /tmp/display.$user)
```

Comment: I try to add  

     user=$1
 
     XAUTHORITY="/home/$user/.Xauthority"
    DISPLAY=$( who | grep -m1 $user.*\( | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[(|)]//g')

before call notify-send, but don't result

Comment: @AlmuHS Are you sure that is right? Your `who ...` for `DISPLAY` does not work here, and `XAUTHORITY` is in my case `/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`. Maybe output them into a file and check if they are right?

Comment: added in main post

Comment: I test this command in the command line, and runs well

Comment: @AlmuHS I've added a workaround that stores `DISPLAY` in `/tmp` and uses `xhost` instead of  `XAUTHORITY` for X authentication.

Comment: Don't runs yet :(

Comment: Does `/tmp/display.$USER` have the right content?

Comment: simply, /tmp/display.almu don't exists

Comment: @AlmuHS Than you did not execute the autostart script.

Comment: I executed it mannually

Comment: ok, after execute autostart script manually, the /tmp/display.almu file has been created, and its content is ":0"

But there isn't notify yet

Comment: @AlmuHS Did you check with xmessage, too?

Comment: Yes, I did this

Comment: I've just seen this post. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203136/how-do-i-run-gui-applications-as-root-by-using-pkexec

Can I create a similar action file to launch notify-send?

Comment: @AlmuHS Maybe. Quite important is the line with allow_gui, I assume. It seems to me notify-send must run as the user who gets notified. If you can set up a rule that allows to execute `notify-send` as desired user without a password prompt, it will probably work. You need to allow something like `su $user -c 'notify-send message'`

Comment: Interestingly, I can successfully run `notify-send` from tty although there is no `DISPLAY` and no `XAUTHORITY` in the enviroment. It seems `notify-send` gets the value from somewhere else.

Comment: I tried `su $user -c 'notify-send message'` in other time. but failed same.

As I knows, `notify-send` takes DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY from DBus

Comment: @AlmuHS `su $user` needs a user password (except root is doing this), otherwise it will fail. Your polkit  script runs as user `polkitd` as seen with output of `id`.  Maybe a polkit rule is possible to allow `pkexec --user $user notify-send MESSAGE` without a password for all $user. I'm not familar with polkit though and cannot provide a polkit/pkexec rule, but I assume it is possible.

Comment: But, I think that polkit launch the script as root. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AlmuHS You did `echo $(id) > /tmp/user` somewhere above, it showed user `polkitd`.

Comment: ok, I didn't remember this

Answer (score 0):

@mviereck

I tried to create a polkit policy file to notify-send, with this contents

```
<policyconfig>
<action id="org.freedesktop.notify-send">
<description>Launch notify-send command</description>
<message>Authentication is required to run the gedit</message>
<icon_name>accessories-text-editor</icon_name>
<defaults>
    <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
    <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
    <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/notify-send</annotate>
<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
</action>
```

I put this file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.notify-send.policy`

But, after press shutdown button, the shutdown menu took a long time to be showed, and notification didn't appeared

Comment: I cannot provide help with polkit rules, I am not familar with them. But I don't see an attempt to allow running notify-send as anther user. Or does `<allow_any>yes</allow_any>` do this? Sorry, can't really help here. Maybe ask a new question like "How to allow running notify-send as another user with pkexec".

Comment: ok, I'll try it