# How to send notification when user press shutdown button in the GUI?

Tags: linux, shutdown, notifications, polkit

I am writing a program to remind extract the pendrive before shutdown.
This program locks shutdown if pendrive is connected, and unlock it if pendrive is disconnected.

For do this, I use a polkit authority file (.pkla), which is copied when pendrive is connected, and removed after pendrive is disconnected

I use polkit 0.105, that don't allows set javascript rules

```
[Shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off;org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions;org.xfce.session.xfsm-  shutdown-helper
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=no
```

With this, I got that shutdown is locked.
But now I want to, furthermore to lock shutdown, the system shows a notification when user press shutdown button (which call any of this polkit actions)

How can I do it?

BTW, the notification don't needs been called by polkit. If there is any form to show the notification when user press shutdown button, although don't use polkit, it's good

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425211/117549 ?

Comment: No, I use polkit < 0.106

Comment: It's the same program, but this do differents action with polkit 0.106 and polkit < 0.106

Comment: If the version information makes this question unique, then the Question should contain it.

Comment: added to the info