# How to allow running notify-send as another user with pkexec?

Tags: linux, polkit, notify-send

As continuation of this question ([How can I send a notification with polkit 0.106?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425211/how-can-i-send-a-notification-with-polkit-0-106)), I've discovered that I have to execute `notify-send` as the user who I want to send notification.

But, with my current config, I can't do this, because polkit execute the script as `polkitd` user, and I can't do `su $user` without known user password.

By this reason, I need to create a new polkit action, to allow execute `notify-send` as other user from polkitd.

My polkit rule is this:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
     if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.consolekit.system.stop" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions" || 
        action.id == "org.xfce.session.xfsm-shutdown-helper")  
     {

        try{    
            polkit.spawn(["/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/check_pendrive.sh", subject.user]);        
            return polkit.Result.YES;

        }catch(error){
            polkit.spawn(["/usr/bin/pendrive-reminder/send_notify.sh", subject.user]);
           return polkit.Result.NO;
        }
    }
});
```

This polkit rule must lock shutdown option in shutdown menu, and shows a notification with `notify-send`, with `send_notify.sh` script, which execute this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=":0"

user=$1
pkexec --user $user notify-send  "Pendrive Reminder" "Shutdown lock enabled. Disconnect pendrive to enable shutdown" -u critical

exit 0
```

I tried to add this polkit policy file:

```
<policyconfig>
    <action id="org.freedesktop.notify-send">
    <description>Launch notify-send command</description>
    <defaults>
        <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
        <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
        <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
    </defaults>
   <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/notify-send</annotate>
   <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
   </action>
</policyconfig>
```

I put this file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.notify-send.policy`

But, after put policy file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/` and press shutdown button, the shutdown menu took a long time to be showed, and notification didn't appeared. The shutdown option is locked correctly

How can I get that polkit can call notify-send from my script?

Comment: Don't use `su $user -c`, try to allow `pkexec --user $user notify-send`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it

Comment: After change this, the problem continues. Shutdown menu takes around 10 seconds in be showed, and notification isn't showed

Comment: Add this in your bash script: `LOG_FILE=/tmp/script.log ;
exec > >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} ) ;
exec 2> >(tee -a ${LOG_FILE} >&2)`. Check the log file afterwards to see possible error messages. Btw.: use @mviereck if you adress me, than I get a notification.

Comment: @mviereck after add this in my script and press shutdown button, the log file is empty

Comment: @mviereck may I could to add `polkitd` to sudoers file, only with notify-send allowed, and execute command with `sudo su $user notify-send`

Comment: ok, add polkitd to sudoers don't runs

Comment: That is possible, but I would not recommend that for a deployed solutions, only for custom home setups. `sudo` is not preset everywhere, for example, debian uses only `su` and `pkexec`. Btw., instead of `sudo su $user` use `sudo -u $user`. The most portable way would be a passwordless `pkexec --user $user notify-send`. I'm quite sure it is possible.

Comment: @mviereck
In any case, add `polkitd ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/notify-send` only allows polkitd to execute `notify-send`, which isn't the problem, so It isn't solve my problem

Comment: I just tried to launch `pkexec --user [myuser] notify-send "hello"` from tty, after doing `export DISPLAY=":0"` 

Executing this as root, the notification has been showed.

So, pkexec can shows the notification from another user

But, in my script not

Comment: I just test to remove my action polkit file, and notification isn't showed, so my action file is correct

@mviereck

Comment: I created a new test user, not root, and repeat the command `pkexec --user almu notify-send "hola"` successfully

Comment: @mviereck read this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a few test, I got this results:

- polkitd is a nologin user
- If I execute this command, to execute my script with polkitd user, shows an error:

  `sudo su polkitd -s /bin/bash -c aux_scripts/send_notify.sh almu`

  `Error executing command as another user: Not authorized`

  `This incident has been reported.`

So, I think that polkitd user is a limited account, who it can't execute commands as other user

As a conclusion, I determine that this action isn't possible to do without modify system internal. I can't allow this in my application, so I can't launch commands as another user from polkit