# Run sudo Exec in .desktop via pkexec: Qt Error

Tags: sudo, virtualbox, .desktop, freedesktop, pkexec

I have a configuration in virtualbox that requires me to run the application with sudo privileges. I have been editing the `.desktop` file to run with sudo (note a simply changing the `Exec` variable to `Exec=sudo virtualbox` does not work even with the appropriate changes to the sudoers file):

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VirtualBox
GenericName=PC virtualization solution

Type=Application
Exec=virtualbox %U
TryExec=VirtualBox
Keywords=virtualization;
Keywords[de]=Virtualisierung;
Keywords[ru]=виртуализация;
MimeType=application/x-virtualbox-vbox;application/x-virtualbox-vbox-extpack;application/x-virtualbox-ovf;application/x-virtualbox-ova;
Icon=virtualbox
Categories=Emulator;System;Utility;
Actions=RootManager;Manager
Comment=Run several virtual systems on a single host computer
Comment[de]=Mehrere virtuelle Maschinen auf einem einzigen Rechner ausführen
Comment[it]=Esegui più macchine virtuali su un singolo computer
Comment[ko]=가상 머신
Comment[pl]=Uruchamianie wielu systemów wirtualnych na jednym komputerze gospodarza
Comment[ru]=Запуск нескольких виртуальных машин на одном компьютере
Comment[sv]=Kör flera virtuella system på en enda värddator

[Desktop Action Manager]
Exec=virtualbox
Name=Open Oracle VM Manager
Name[de]=Oracle VM Manager öffnen

[Desktop Action RootManager]
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'sudo -i /usr/bin/virtualbox;'"
Name=Open Manager as Admin
```

The above works and is an ok workaround for the time being but notice that the authentication happens in the gnome-terminal. I would like to bypass this with `pkexec` (e.g. `Exec=pkexec virtualbox`) but I get the following error:

```
 ~$ pkexec virtualbox
Qt WARNING: could not connect to display 
Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have identified some possible culprits/solutions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041588/virtualbox-not-launching-on-ubuntu-18-04-qt-lib-problem
- [How do I run GUI applications as root by using pkexec?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203136/how-do-i-run-gui-applications-as-root-by-using-pkexec)

I have a feeling my problem is not associated so much with the first link since the application works fine without the use of `pkexec`. The second link adds custom actions to the freedesktop policykit which looks pretty involved but might be what I need.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

second link worked:

```
$ cat /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.virtualbox.policy 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
    <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.virtualbox">
    <description>Run VirtualBox as Admin</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to run VirtualBox as administrator</message>
    <icon_name>virtualbox</icon_name>
    <defaults>
        <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
        <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
        <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/virtualbox</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
    </action>
</policyconfig>
```

and

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/virtualbox.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=VirtualBox
GenericName=PC virtualization solution

Type=Application
Exec=pkexec virtualbox %U
TryExec=VirtualBox
Keywords=virtualization;
Keywords[de]=Virtualisierung;
Keywords[ru]=виртуализация;
MimeType=application/x-virtualbox-vbox;application/x-virtualbox-vbox-extpack;application/x-virtualbox-ovf;application/x-virtualbox-ova;
Icon=virtualbox
Categories=Emulator;System;Utility;
Actions=RootManager;Manager
Comment=Run several virtual systems on a single host computer
Comment[de]=Mehrere virtuelle Maschinen auf einem einzigen Rechner ausführen
Comment[it]=Esegui più macchine virtuali su un singolo computer
Comment[ko]=가상 머신
Comment[pl]=Uruchamianie wielu systemów wirtualnych na jednym komputerze gospodarza
Comment[ru]=Запуск нескольких виртуальных машин на одном компьютере
Comment[sv]=Kör flera virtuella system på en enda värddator

[Desktop Action Manager]
Exec=virtualbox
Name=Open Oracle VM Manager
Name[de]=Oracle VM Manager öffnen

[Desktop Action RootManager]
Exec=pkexec virtualbox
Name=Open Oracle VM Manager (admin)
```