# Desktop Launcher not Working on Elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os, .desktop, xampp

I'm still learning about how to make a desktop launcher. I'm trying to make a desktop launcher for the XAMPP Manager (a.k.a. the GUI).

This is the location of the .run file:

```
/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

And here's the desktop entry i'm trying to make with the name xampp-gui.desktop :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP Services
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Type=Application
Categories=Programming
Terminal=false
```

I also have done the `chmod +x` to the .run file and the .desktop file.
When i tried to launch it, nothing happens. Perhaps i did any mistake or missing something?

Comment: Hi. It will not run with `sudo`. You likely want a graphical prompt for password, which can be achieved with `pkexec` as explained in the answer to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203136/). If you want to start the application as root without a prompt, there are other options.

Comment: What is the other options? And, tried with the pkexec, still no luck for now.

Comment: Never mind, i got it working using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641593/pkexec-command-in-a-desktop-file) workaround. Thank you.